# Laravel, get data from api ans save it in database

Tags: database, laravel, api, get, guzzle

i installed guzzle the laravel package, and i display the data from an api. I want to save this data in database. I can't find enough resources to do it

[route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7suY.png)

[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjlaD.png)

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9tsF.png)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i tried to display the raw data from the api, i was successful. then I posted only one data (of the client) and I tried to save, I could not. but I want to save the data first then display it. you will not have an example

Comment: @OthmaneHaddouche what Aless55 means is that you have to add the code you have tried to your question. That way we can help you with YOUR code.

Comment: You want to get data from API and put it in your database?

Comment: Controller
class RequestController extends Controller
{
    public function getAllOrders(Request $request)
    {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $res=$client->request('GET', 'https://nextimes.dz/wp-json/wc-analytics/orders', ['auth' => ['ck_e53c61c53e04fe95cefd9b6ecbd1323e3470b4d6', 'cs_c737add5943fec2ede120c266c6f9ecbd41973c9']]);
        $jsonArray = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true); 
        return $jsonArray;
Route::get('/orders',[RequestController::class,'getAllOrders']);
this is how I get all the data, I want to save some in my database

Comment: Mahbod Ahmadi yes !

Comment: don't post code as comment.. edit you question please.

Answer (score 1):

```php
public function all() {
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'http://api'); // Pass the third parameter as an array if you have to set headers
    $response = json_decode($response->getBody(), true); // The API response data

    // You should put your data in the loop.
    $data = collect($response); // So we create an collection to use helper methods
    $data->map(function ($item) {

        // Now, we can save the data to the database with two methods

        // Model:
        YourModel::create([
            'column' => $item['key'],
        ]);

        // Query builder:
        DB::table('your_table')->insert([
            'column' => $item['key'],
        ]);
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you very much I can add my data to the database thanks to this link :
https://devdojo.com/bobbyiliev/how-to-consume-an-external-api-with-laravel-and-guzzle?fbclid=IwAR3y7wo4_RwokRL49hibn2dJtkUGsIJS4gfeSIyRawE_sWMgUQ65m-aWGos